# Function from 1-dim. sphere to real line

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

This is either trivial or wrong:

Let $f:\mathbb S^1 \to \mathbb R$, where $\mathbb S^1 = [-1/2,1/2]/(-1/2\sim1/2)$ is the one-dimensional sphere, be such that $f\in L^1\big(\mathbb S^1\big)$; does it make sense to define $\tilde f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $\tilde f(x)= f(x)$ if $x\in (-1/2,1/2]$, and $\tilde f(x)= 0$ otherwise, and to say that for any $\kappa\in \mathbb Z$ $$\mathcal F \tilde f(u)|_{u=\kappa}:=\int_{\mathbb R}\tilde f(x)e^{2\pi i \kappa x }dx=\int_{\mathbb S^1} f(x) e^{2\pi i \kappa x }dx=:\mathcal F f(\kappa)?$$

I have some results about Fourier transforms of functions on $\mathbb R$ that I now need for functions on $\mathbb S^1$ and this argument would allow me to avoid reproving them. The definition of $\tilde f$ and the equality above seem to make sense computationally but for some reason my intuition tells me that they do not mathematically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manipulation you described is correct, but it usually does not give an easy way to obtain results for the Fourier transform on $S^1$ from the results for the Fourier transform on $\mathbb{R}$. For example, $\tilde f$ is typically discontinuous even if $f$ is continuous, which is an obstacle to relating the smoothness of $f$ to the decay of its Fourier coefficients.

What happens in such cases is: $\mathcal F\tilde f$ has slow decay at infinity, but dips toward zero at integer points, thus aligning with the quickly decaying Fourier coefficients $\hat f(n)$. A simple illustration is $f\equiv 1$, where all Fourier coefficients except one are zero. Since $\tilde f=\chi_{[-1/2,1/2]}$, its Fourier transform is the [sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) with some normalization: it is pretty heavy-tailed (not in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$) but duly vanishes at the integers.

A relevant result on the relation between the Fourier transform of a function and the Fourier series of its periodization is the [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula).

Comment: Comments in reverse order: 

- Indeed, I am using the PSF in several quantities but there is one for which it does not apply as the function comes given in the periodic setting straight away. In some sense, I am trying to find a result in the opposite direction to PSF and that works for my purposes.

Comment: - Great point: it had crossed my mind but did not give it much importance because, crucially, what I am interested in is the behaviour of $\mathcal F f$ in compact intervals around the origin. Still, great to point it out as a warning!

Comment: - So in no place of the manipulation does the periodic nature of $f$ play a role? And all that matters is that its values coincide with those of $\tilde f$ in the interval?